# HTML file not loading properly in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am trying to integrate my django app with a admin dashboard from [github](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/light-bootstrap-dashboard). I can see after my successful log in the app get directed to dashboard but only the HTML part is loading i can't see any fancy things getting added to my dashboard

[image: dashboard].

It should have been looking like the one screenshot given in github [link](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/light-bootstrap-dashboard). I am not a regular frontend developer so it's getting hard for me figure out where the mistake is.

**Dashboard.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>Light Bootstrap Dashboard by Creative Tim</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type='text/css' />

    <!-- Animation library for notifications   -->
    <!--<link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/animate.min.css' %}" type='text/css' />
    <!--  Light Bootstrap Table core CSS    -->
    <!--<link href="assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css?v=1.4.0" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/animate.min.css' %}" type='text/css' />

    <!--  CSS for Demo Purpose, don't include it in your project     -->
    <!--<link href="assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/demo.css' %}" type='text/css' />

    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}"  type='text/css'  />-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' %}" type='text/css' />-->
    <!--<link href="assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <!--<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css' %}" type='text/css' />-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css' %}" type='text/css' />

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-image="img/sidebar-5.jpg">

    <!--

        Tip 1: you can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="blue | azure | green | orange | red | purple"
        Tip 2: you can also add an image using data-image tag

    -->
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text">
                    Creative Tim
                </a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="dashboard.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-graph"></i>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="user.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>
                        <p>User Profile</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="table.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-note2"></i>
                        <p>Table List</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="typography.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-news-paper"></i>
                        <p>Typography</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="icons.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-science"></i>
                        <p>Icons</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="maps.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-map-marker"></i>
                        <p>Maps</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="notifications.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-bell"></i>
                        <p>Notifications</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active-pro">
                    <a href="upgrade.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-rocket"></i>
                        <p>Upgrade to PRO</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                                <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Dashboard</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                    <b class="caret hidden-lg hidden-md"></b>
                                    <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
                                        5 Notifications
                                        <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </p>
                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another notification</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Search</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                           <a href="">
                               <p>Account</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <p>
                                        Dropdown
                                        <b class="caret"></b>
                                    </p>

                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>Log out</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="separator hidden-lg"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">Email Statistics</h4>
                                <p class="category">Last Campaign Performance</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div id="chartPreferences" class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>

                                <div class="footer">
                                    <div class="legend">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Open
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Bounce
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Unsubscribe
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Campaign sent 2 days ago
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">Users Behavior</h4>
                                <p class="category">24 Hours performance</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div id="chartHours" class="ct-chart"></div>
                                <div class="footer">
                                    <div class="legend">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Open
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Click
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Click Second Time
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="fa fa-history"></i> Updated 3 minutes ago
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card ">
                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">2014 Sales</h4>
                                <p class="category">All products including Taxes</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div id="chartActivity" class="ct-chart"></div>

                                <div class="footer">
                                    <div class="legend">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Tesla Model S
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> BMW 5 Series
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Data information certified
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card ">
                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">Tasks</h4>
                                <p class="category">Backend development</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="table-full-width">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
                                                        <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Sign contract for "What are conference organizers afraid of?"</td>
                                                <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Task" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" checked>
                                                        <label for="checkbox2"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Lines From Great Russian Literature? Or E-mails From My Boss?</td>
                                                <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Task" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                                                        <label for="checkbox3"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Flooded: One year later, assessing what was lost and what was found when a ravaging rain swept through metro Detroit
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Task" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" checked>
                                                        <label for="checkbox4"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Create 4 Invisible User Experiences you Never Knew About</td>
                                                <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Task" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox">
                                                        <label for="checkbox5"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Read "Following makes Medium better"</td>
                                                <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Task" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox" checked>
                                                        <label for="checkbox6"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Unfollow 5 enemies from twitter</td>
                                                <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Task" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                                <div class="footer">
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="fa fa-history"></i> Updated 3 minutes ago
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav class="pull-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Company
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Portfolio
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                               Blog
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <p class="copyright pull-right">
                    &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com">Creative Tim</a>, made with love for a better web
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
</div>


</body>

    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!--<script src="assets/js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!--  Charts Plugin -->
    <!--<script src="assets/js/chartist.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="{% static 'js/chartist.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
    <!--<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>-->
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-notify.js' %}"></script>

    <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table Core javascript and methods for Demo purpose -->
    <!--<script src="assets/js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js?v=1.4.0"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="{% static 'js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js?v=1.4.0' %}"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="{% static 'js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js?v=1.4.0' %}"></script>-->


    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
    <!--<script src="assets/js/demo.js"></script>-->
    <script src="{% static 'js/demo.js' %}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            demo.initChartist();

            $.notify({
                icon: 'pe-7s-gift',
                message: "Welcome to <b>Light Bootstrap Dashboard</b> - a beautiful freebie for every web developer."

            },{
                type: 'info',
                timer: 4000
            });

        });
    </script>

</html>
```

All my media content is present in static folder as i ran collect static and running my localhost i can see 200 response for all my css ,etc.

My Debug points:
I can see it is possibly not working starting from the div class.

**Note**
I can paste the code from other files as per requirements here

Edit1: Adding the output from console

[image: Console error]
[image: static folder]

Edit2 : Adding demo.js file ,it is showing debounce is not defined. pfa the second last screenshot
Adding settings.py

**Settings.py**

```
import os
import warnings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from os.path import dirname

warnings.simplefilter('error', DeprecationWarning)

BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
CONTENT_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'content')

SECRET_KEY = 'NhfTvayqggTBPswCXXhWaN69HuglgZIkM'

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Vendor apps
    'bootstrap4',

    # Application apps
    'main',
    'accounts',
    'dashboard',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(CONTENT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(CONTENT_DIR, 'tmp/emails')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'kmickey34@yahoo.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'test@example.com'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CONTENT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CONTENT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(CONTENT_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Comment: It looks to me like either some CSS or Javascript isn't being loaded properly. Either that or some Javascript code isn't executing properly. Do you see any errors in the development console?

Comment: @JonahBishop i have edited and added the console output. It seems like there is some problem with js

Comment: Those issues are likely your problem. You'll need to go through each, correcting the errors as you go.

Comment: Please show us a pic of your static folder. There may be a file missing. Also if you have set debug to false in your settings then you won't be able to serve static and media files

Comment: @JonahBishop i resolved those by removing that function from my demo.js which i was not using anywhere.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi screenshot has been added

Comment: can you add your `settings.py` file

Comment: @ShafikurRahmanShaon I added the setting.py. Due to limit on characters i tried adding the most of the details from the file, anyhow if you need any more info please let me know

Comment: is your static files in `your_project_root_directory/static`

Comment: @ShafikurRahmanShaon seems to me it is placed right, may be you can also check from the last screenshot i shared?

Comment: change this just for test. `CONTENT_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'source/content')`, let me know is it works or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185803/discussion-between-user7422128-and-shafikur-rahman-shaon).

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.
2. In your settings file, define STATIC_URL, for example:

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
3. In your templates, use the static template tag to build the URL for the given relative 
   path using the configured STATICFILES_STORAGE.

   example:

   {% load static %}

Comment: In your Dashboard.html   please  write  {% load static %}